# Intellij IDEA How to Refactor mainClassName in file biuld.gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, build.gradle

In IDEA i refactored class name from MyFirstProgram to MyFirstProgram1,
but IDEA did not change "mainClassName" in the file biuld.gradle

I had a

**MyFirstProgram.java:**

```
public class MyFirstProgram {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, beatch!");
    }
}
```

and 
**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "MyFirstProgram"
```

Refactored MyFirstProgram.java to **MyFirstProgram1.java:**

```
public class MyFirstProgram {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, beatch!");
    }
}
```

and I expect a change build.gradle to:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "MyFirstProgram1"
```

using button fron screenshot from training course:

[I want to see this button in order to use the refactor in file build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWvjH.jpg)

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please report on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Reported https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186557